# How to create and name a folder each time a file is uploaded in PHP?

Tags: php

How do i create a folder for each upload but auto number it when each folder is created?
lets say i upload a file then a folder 1 is created inside the uploaded folder, then someone else or the same person uploads another file then a folder 2 will be created in the uploaded folder? Is there any way to do this?

Here is what i have right now

```
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($temp,"uploaded/".$name);
$url = "www.Mysite.com/uploaded/$name";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `asktemp` VALUE ('','$suserid','$askeduserid','$name','$url')");
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a folder per upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$upload_dir = 'uploaded/';
$dir = 1;
while(file_exists($upload_dir.$dir) and is_dir($upload_dir.$dir)) {
    $dir++;
}
mkdir($upload_dir.$dir);
```

That creates directories like `1`,`2`,`3` etc

And then just put:

```
move_uploaded_file($temp,$upload_dir.$dir.'/'.$name);
```

to upload your file to the new created directory.

Comment: Hi this works great! The only thing is that the folder is being created on the main folder and not in the sub folder which is uploaded. Here is what i have right now $url="http://mysite.com/uploaded/$name";                              I tried doing this but it did not work $url="http://mysite.com/uploaded/mkdir($dir)/$name";

Comment: Changed my answer with a default upload folder. Now it will create directories in your `uploaded` folder.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) in combination with [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to create unique paths.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`mkdir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) and assign the folder name dynamically, for example:

```
$folder_name = $path . "folder_" . $i;
mkdir($folder_name);
```

To calculate `$i`, you may for example count number of folders and add 1.

Answer (score -3):

To get the auto_increment ID assigned to a new row, use `mysql_insert_id()`.

Comment: What is wrong with this approach? Yes, he didn't mention how to create a folder, but why it's better to count how many folders exists when OP adds an entry into database each time he uploads a file and `id`'s are unique?